# Camel route filter by file

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I know this question was asked a lot of time but i'm trying multiple solutions and can't make it work.

I am really new to Apache Camel, and I'm using it with Spring Boot.

What I want to do is have a global route to one of my folders, and when a file arrive in this folder trigger a process depending on a part of the file name.

Currently I just setup a route and try to trigger the process only for one of my file:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?moveFailed=errors&delete=true").choice()
            .when(header("CamelFileName").endsWith(".zip"))
            .process(myprocessor)
            .end();
}
```

And my test:

```
@EndpointInject("mock:result") protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);

        // Build a test route by adding an mock endpoint to the route
        RouteDefinition route =  mcc.getRouteDefinition(ROUTE_NAME);
        RouteDefinition testRoute = route.to(resultEndpoint);
```

But here I have a `null pointer exeception` in the last line.

EDIT: Here is my Route definition

```
@Component public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public static final String ROUTE_NAME = "myRoute";

    private final Processor myProcessor;

    @Autowired public MyRoute(@Qualifier("my.processor") Processor myProcessor) {
        this.myProcessor= myProcessor;
    }

    @Override public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?moveFailed=errors&delete=true").routeId(ROUTE_NAME).choice()
                .when(header("CamelFileName").startsWith("ACK")).process(myProcessor).end();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at the camel file watcher component. This however requires at least Camel 3.0

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-watch-component.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all: What is the `ROUTE_NAME` you pass to get the route definition in your test? Because you have not defined a route ID in your route, Camel automatically generates a route ID. Have you really defined the generated route name in a constant? This name can change when you add other routes.

You should set a static self-defined route ID

```
from("whatever").routeId("import-file-route").choice()...
```

So that you can get the Route definition with a robust reference

```
mcc.getRouteDefinition("import-file-route")
```

Second: as far as I know, you cannot just call `.to` on the route definition. If you want to add a mock endpoint to your route, you have to [advice the route](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/AdviceWith).

This can be done for example by adding this method to your test-class...

```
public void addMockToEndOfRoute() throws Exception {
    context.getRouteDefinition(""import-file-route"").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            weaveAddLast().to("mock:result");
        }
    });
}
```

... and then call `addMockToEndOfRoute()` in the test method.

**Added to answer**

Currently you import all files and try to limit routing to files with a specific name. Problem is that all imported files are deleted. So when you later try to read the corresponding DATA file, it could already be deleted.

You can limit the [file-consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html) to files with a specific name pattern with the `include` option that takes a regex

```
from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?include=ACK.*&...")
```

Like this only files with name "ACK[whatever]" are imported, so you can remove your [content based router](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-based-router-eip.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I'm now able to send a file to my camel route inside the test but I'm still in trouble with the route configuration, I have ACK files and DATA files that are coming in the same folder, and I want to trigger the process only on ACK files (and in the process I move and use the DATA file). I've added my entire route configuration, I don't understand why every file go to my processor, and not only ones that start with "ACK", do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? That ever file is imported or that every file is imported AND routed to your processor? The first is obvious, the second should not be the case according to your route

Comment: When I move a file in my folder with a name not starting by ACK the process is triggered with this file, and I don't want this. My need is to trigger the process only if the file start by ACK

Comment: I have extended my answer

Comment: A long time after your first answer but do you know how to use the include pattern to search if the file contains a string, and not start with it ?

Comment: I don't know if negative lookaheads are supported, but if yes this regex should match filenames containing `ACK`, but not if they begin with `ACK`: `^(?!ACK).+ACK.*$`